# User roles - enable custom posts disable posts

Tags: custom-post-types, users, user-roles

Im just wondering if its possible to create user role that allows to write/edit custom post type for example: Consultants, but not allow to write normal posts (used for as news for example).

I know that if user wants to edit posts its a must to have edit_post enabled for him. Question is if i can create something like: edit_[custom_post_type] or something?

Thanks in avance if anyone can help me with this issue...

Kindest regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that Justin Tadlock's [Members Plugin](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/17/members-wordpress-plugin) would make this very easy for you.

Comment: Yes was about to write this. That figures out all my problems :D. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

When you register your custom post type, explicitly set the capability type;

```
register_post_type( 'my_type',  array(
    'capability_type' => 'my_type',
    // other args
) );
```

Now by default, only super admins should be able to add/edit/delete them, until you grant other roles the relevant capabilities (for example, as @tnorthcutt suggested, using the [Members Plugin](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/17/members-wordpress-plugin)).

```
[edit_post] => edit_my_type
[read_post] => read_my_type
[delete_post] => delete_my_type
[edit_posts] => edit_my_type
[edit_others_posts] => edit_others_my_type
[publish_posts] => publish_my_type
[read_private_posts] => read_private_my_type
```